# socket.get() AND socket.set() gives problems

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm using NodeJs v0.10.28 and everytime i try to login to the chat i get a error

`TypeError: Object #<Socket> has no method 'set' at Socket.<anonymous>`

And if i'm deleting the lines it works but not working right.

What is the wrong thing in this code

```
// get the name of the sender
socket.get('nickname', function (err, name) {
  console.log('Chat message by ', name);
  console.log('error ', err);
  sender = name;
});
```

AND

```
socket.set('nickname', name, function () {
  // this kind of emit will send to all! :D
  io.sockets.emit('chat', {
    msg : "Welcome, " + name + '!', 
    msgr : "Nickname"
  });
});
```

**FULL CODE**

http://pastebin.com/vJx7MYfE

Answer (score 8):

You have to set the nickname property directly in the socket!

From socket.io website:

> The old io.set() and io.get() methods are deprecated and only supported for backwards compatibility. Here is a translation of an old authorization example into middleware-style.

Also, from an example of the socket.io website :

```
// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};
var numUsers = 0;

    // when the client emits 'add user', this listens and executes
  socket.on('add user', function (username) {
    // we store the username in the socket session for this client
    socket.username = username;
    // add the client's username to the global list
    usernames[username] = username;
    ++numUsers;
    addedUser = true;
    socket.emit('login', {
      numUsers: numUsers
    });
    // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
    socket.broadcast.emit('user joined', {
      username: socket.username,
      numUsers: numUsers
    });
  });
```

Check the example here : https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js

Comment: @Ludo, Hi, this works fine for me, but when I am using different namespaces, the session data does not persist between namespaces, like suppose I have a namespace A where I set `socket.username` and I have a namespace B where I want to access this `socket.username`. How do I do this? Is there a way to persist the session data between namespaces?

Answer (score 3):

Like what Ludo said, set the nickname property directly in the socket:

```
// get the name of the sender
var name = socket.nickname;
console.log('Chat message by ', name);
console.log('error ', err);
sender = name;
```

and

```
// this kind of emit will send to all! :D
socket.nickname = name;
io.sockets.emit('chat', {
  msg : "Welcome, " + name + '!', 
  msgr : "Nickname"
});
```

Comment: @Iyen, Hi, this works fine for me, but when I am using different namespaces, the session data does not persist between namespaces, like suppose I have a namespace A where I set `socket.username` and I have a namespace B where I want to access this `socket.username`. How do I do this? Is there a way to persist the session data between namespaces?